Iterate through each days in a given month
I have a pine script indicator that gives some statistics about each month that I use but only on the monthly chart.
I want to get the day when the high and day when the low occurs for each monthly bar. I have looked at the security() method however I can not seem to implement it properly such that it accurately returns the day.
The goal eventually is to display the most common day the high and low occurs on average for each month.
I have reduced the script to only handle Januarys to keep it short but it essentially does the same thing for all months:
//@version=5
indicator("Monthly Stats", overlay = true)

startDate = input.time(timestamp("Jan 01 2000 09:30:00 UTC-5"), "Start date", group = 'Lookback')
useMaxBars = input.bool(false, "Use Maximum Bars", group = 'Lookback')
lookBack = (time - startDate) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds("M"))

if useMaxBars == true
    lookBack := bar_index

januarys = 0.0
positiveJanuarys = 0.0
negativeJanuarys = 0.0

if barstate.islast and timeframe.ismonthly
    for i = lookBack to 1
        m = time[i]

        if month(m) == 1
            januarys += 1
            if open[i] < close[i]    
                positiveJanuarys += 1
            else 
                negativeJanuarys += 1
        // The rest of the months 

    januaryPR = (positiveJanuarys / januarys) * 100
    // The rest of the months

    var string GP2 = "Display"
    string  tableYposInput = input.string("top", "Panel position", inline = "11", options = ["top", "middle", "bottom"], group = GP2)
    string  tableXposInput = input.string("right", "", inline = "11", options = ["left", "center", "right"], group = GP2)

    var table panel = table.new(tableYposInput + "_" + tableXposInput, 8, 13)
    if barstate.islast
        // Table header.
        table.cell(panel, 0, 0, "Month", bgcolor = neutColorInput, text_color = color.white)
        table.cell(panel, 1, 0, "Pos Months", bgcolor = neutColorInput, text_color = color.white)

        //table body
        table.cell(panel, 0, 1, "January", bgcolor = neutColorInput, text_color = color.white)
        //The rest of the months

        //Percent of days with a positive reture
        table.cell(panel, 1, 1, januaryPRS, bgcolor = neutColorInput, text_color = color.white)
        

